# Handling more many to many relationships in dynamodb single table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am designing a single dynamodb table for an institute. It has entities like **institute, students, subjects and teachers**. The relationships between them are like this.

- institute - students many to many
- institute - teachers many to many
- institute - subjects many to many

I selected  **institute id** as **PK** and **location** as **SK**. But there are more many to many relationships in this scenario. So how to handle this kind of situation in was dynamodb?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

DynamoDB is a noSQL database where you should denormalize and duplicate your data as much as possible. You are thinking in SQL and are trying to normalize your data, you need to switch your mindset.

Create an item for each institute, student, teacher and subject.
Create a `students` map or list (I prefer a map with an ID as the key) inside institute, and a `institutes` map or list inside students. Those maps or lists are made of copies of your original items:

```
inst-0 | USA  | Institute name                              | { stud-0: { name: John }, studo-1: { name: Matt } }
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
stud-0        | John | { inst-0: { name: Institute name } } |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
stud-1        | Matt | { inst-0: { name: Institute name } } |
```

The downside here is that you need to update each copy when the original changes. But it is generally not a problem unless your data changes very frequently.

If your copied data changes frequently, you can create an intermediate relationnal item, but then maybe a relationnal database is more appropriate for your project.

You could also create an item for each student and just store a reference to those student into institute items. But here again you are not denormalizing your data, but it could be a viable solution if your data changes frequently or if you have a big amount of student in each institute.